# PHP SQL Table Entry hyperlinking

Tags: php, sql

Below is my Php code. Would anyone be able to tell me how to remove the hyperlinking of every single SQL entry in this code?

As I don't want my users to click into any of the entries and then directed to another web page. I just want a static table with entries from my sql database.

Thanks very much!

```
<?
 #Get the event id from $_GET
    $int_event_id = $_GET["EventID"];
    if((int)$int_event_id)
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=clubresults', 'root', '12345678');
    #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT EventName, Score, Place from results WHERE EventID ='$int_event_id' ORDER By EventID ASC");
$rowset = array();

if ($query) {
  while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // Build array of rows
    $rowset[] = $row;
  }    

  // Output header first
  $headrow = $rowset[0];
  print("<table border=\"1\">\n<tr>\n");
  // Use $rowset[0] to write the table heading
  foreach ($headrow as $col => $val) {
    printf("<th>%s</th>\n", $col);
  }
  print("</tr>");

  // Then output table rows.
  // Outer loop iterates over row
  foreach ($rowset as $row) {
     print("<tr>");
     // Inner loop iterates over columns using $col => $val
     foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
        // We don't know your column names, but substitute the first column (the ID) for FIRSTCOL here
        printf("<td><a href=\"index.php?ID=%s\">%s</a></td>\n", $row['EventID'],$val);
     }
     print("</tr>");
  }
}}
print("</table>");
?>
```

Comment: remove `<a>` from your `printf()`

Comment: using printf to insert a var into a string is ... overkill. `echo "<th>$col</th>\n";` works just as well. printf should only be used if you're using it to apply formatting to whatever you're inserting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change this line:

```
printf("<td><a href=\"index.php?ID=%s\">%s</a></td>\n", $row['EventID'],$val);
```

To this you should be fine:

```
printf("<td>%s</td>\n", $val);
```

Comment: ah terrific! i know it was that line but I just cant figure out what bit to delete haha thanks so much!

Comment: If you accept the answers that help you you're much more likely to get good answers in the future.